# Focusing element via binding doesn't always work

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Given following view model:

```
export class ExpandingInput {  
    // ctor
    constructor() {
        this.expanded = false;
    }

    // actions
    toggle() {
        this.expanded = !this.expanded;
    }
}
```

and template:

```
<template>

    <div class="expanded-input wrapper">
        <input focus.trigger="toggle()" />

        <textarea if.bind="expanded"
                  focus.bind="expanded"
                  blur.trigger="toggle()"
                  rows="4">
        </textarea>
    </div>

</template>
```

The behavior is that when I first click/tab into/otherwise focus the input element, the textarea element shows up and is focused. Then I click somewhere else, so that the textarea looses focus. Now when I again click on the input, the textarea shows up but is not focused (input element is).

Expected/desired behavior would be for the html elements to always behave consistently, not only on the first time :).

Two notes: if I remove the `if.bind expression`, it works. I went around this problem by not using `if.bind` and instead binding css classes to hide/show element like that `class="${expanded ? 'show' : 'hide'}"` but I don't think the former should work as it is now.

Comment: It wurks! Could you please post this comment as an answer, so that I could accept it? Also - could you please point me to the docs where this behavior is described?

Comment: sure, posted. you can find links to the docs in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the textarea's focus state *actively* alters the rendering (detaches it from the DOM), its `focus`/`blur` event listeners are detached as well, so they only work the first time.

From [the docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-basics/8):

> […] `if` removes the element entirely from the DOM, and `show` toggles the `aurelia-hide` CSS class which controls the element's visibility.

To avoid this without having to worry about (re-)binding listeners, *use the `show` conditional instead of `if`*.